# How can I detect when user swipes out a push notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When a user receives or taps on a push notification in iOS, I can detect that by implementing the `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)` method in `AppDelegate` (depending if I checked/unchecked "Remote notifications" in Capabilities -> Background Mode).

However, I'd also like to be notified when the user ignores the notification by swiping it out of the screen. Is it possible? If so then how?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it is not possible.

Comment: It's Possble Ios 10 And Above. You create a custom notification:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191694/how-to-detect-clear-notifications

Comment: There is no conventional way for it. But with iOS 10 we have a way. Add Service Extention to your app, when you receive push notification, store notification data in userdefault. This way you will be able to store all the notifications. Now when the next time you open your app, fetch all the notifications from device notification centre, and check for all the missing notifications by comparing them to the ones stored in Userdefault. In this way you will come to know which all notifications were swiped out.