# How to detect "Clear" for local notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I am trying to add custom logic for when a user hits "clear" on a particular notification (local notification).  I thought that I could use UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier to detect this but it's not working.  I've looked at several posts here and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Ideas?

...in my AppDelegate:

```
let ncDelegate = NotificationCenterDelegate()

func setCategories() {
    
    let clearCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "clear.category",
    actions: [], intentIdentifiers: [], options: .customDismissAction)
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([clearCategory])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        self.printError(error, location: "Request Authorization")
    }
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = ncDelegate
    setCategories()
    return true
}
```

...and in ncDelegate:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    
    if action == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier {
        //.."Clear" button hit... do something
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Nothing seems to happen when I hit "clear" on an individual notification (or when I hit "x").  The "if statement" checking for UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier never gets triggered. What am I missing?

Edited for clarification...  I'm not trying to add a custom button to "clear" the notification.  I know how to do that.  I'm trying to use Apple's "Clear" button when you swipe left on a notification.

So...
Not this ->
[image]

But this instead ->

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @Ashish Sadly, no. And I've changed up my logic now for this project, so I'm not really concentrating on this issue right now.  I just wanted to let you know.  If I do revisit this and find a solution, I will post back here. Sorry I can't be of more help

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I had able to detect a **Clear** event with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56952562/9256497) solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a previous comment from someone (and sorry that's not here but he/she deleted it for some reason), I took a closer look at my categories and how I'm setting content.categoryIdentifier when setting up my notification.  I do have some custom buttons also (snooze, cancel) but the whole problem is because I used options: .hiddenPreviewsShowTitle for this particular category (my main category) instead of options: .customDismissAction. I didn't need to create a whole separate category like above in my original code snippet. **I just needed to use ->**

```
let myMainCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "main.category", actions: [snoozeAction, cancelAction], intentIdentifiers: [], hiddenPreviewsBodyPlaceholder: "k123", options: .customDismissAction)

... and the following when setting up the notification ...

content.categoryIdentifier = "main.category"
```

According to Apple's doc, **UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier "is delivered *only* if the notification’s category object was configured with the customDismissAction option**..." I have to do more testing but I think this will solve my issue. Much thanks to the person who responded previously.  Your comment did help me figure this out :)